# Qt - Implementing QKeyEvent

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-events

How do I implement keyboard listening in Qt? I have the following setup that's not working. I have two classes, gameLogic and gameView. gameView has an instance of gameLogic:

```
gameView::gameView(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    logic = new gameLogic(6);
    logic->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus); //in one of the articles I read, this was supposed to fix the issue. It doesn't for me.
    this->resize(1200, 700);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: white");
    QString str;
    str.setNum(logic->n);
    connect(logic, SIGNAL(playerStepped(int, int)), this, SLOT(movePlayer(int, int)));    
}
```

And in gameLogic I am handling the keystrokes as follows:

```
void gameLogic::keybrdStep( QKeyEvent * keypressed )
{
    if (keypressed->key() == Qt::Key_Q) {
        _message = new QMessageBox;
        _message->setText("Q");
        _message->exec();
    }
}
```

No matter how many times I push the button Q, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Which part am I missing? I'm on Linux Mint with the latest version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void gameLogic::keybrdStep( QKeyEvent * keypressed )
> ```

Where did you get the method name "keybrdStep" from?  Who do you think should call it?

The name of the method you need to override to get key presses is [QWidget::keyPressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)

Comment: Oh!!! I didn't think I'm overriding a function, I thought any function with a QKeyEvent would do! Stupid me! Thank you very much!